# VB expressions to help search through scraped data in UiPath

Tags: vb.net, uipath

I have made a process that reads PDFs and **scrapes** their text in UiPath. I am struggling to come up with a regular expression that I can use to search for a PO Number. The text that comes from the **scrape** is fairly unstructured so my best bet is to search for a set of numbers that starts with a 'PO' with no space. For example, "PO1234567890". I will be setting a variable so the system knows that no PO number was found if the string doesn't come up with anything. Any reference material would be welcome as I am a beginner to VB. Thanks!

I have researched and cannot find a way to do the type of search I would like to do.

I expect to be able to search for a "PO1234567890" and no let something like "PO" save. So I somehow need to be able to search for "PO - two digits" and any numbers following without whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the following:

```
Dim Regex As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

Regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("PO[0-9]+")
Regex.Matches(SearchString)
```

The regex string `PO[0-9]+` means:

PO followed by at least one number

if you want more digits for example 3... just use `PO[0-9]{3}[0-9]*` that means:

PO followed by three numbers and as numbers as it can match.

If you need help using regex matches just ask.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That helps a ton! More simple than I would have thought. I will check and see if that works for me.

Comment: @NathanKeil Just remember to up-vote and mark as answer if it does... thank you!

Comment: I tried but sadly I have less than 15 reputations. My votes are not counted. Thank you again.